# List.remove not removing the index

Tags: python, list

For some reason one term is not getting removed from the list

My if condition checks out correct and int(str(timeleft)[0:2]) < 0 comes out as true and if its true its supposed to remove that index from the list but that doesn't happen for some reason

```
def racetimings():
    race_timings = [['Practice 1', '28/10/2022', '23:30:00'], 
    ['Practice 2', '29/10/2022', '02:30:00'], ['Practice 3', 
    '29/10/2022', '22:30:00'], ['Qualifying', '30/10/2022', 
    '01:30:00'], ['Race', '31/10/2022', '01:30:00']]
for char in race_timings:
    timenow = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    deadline = char[1][6:10] + "-" + char[1][3:5] + "-" + char[1] 
    [0:2] + " " + char[2]
    start = datetime.strptime(timenow, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    ends = datetime.strptime(deadline, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    timeleft = (ends - start)
    if int(str(timeleft)[0:2]) < 0:
        race_timings.remove(char)
return race_timings
```

timeleft output is -1 days,....

Comment: if condition comes out as true when i checked but the char is not getting removed .The first one gets removed but the second one doesnt get removed                                      
 the list:[['Practice 1', '28/10/2022', '23:30:00'], ['Practice 2', '29/10/2022', '02:30:00'], ['Practice 3', '29/10/2022', '22:30:00'], ['Qualifying', '30/10/2022', '01:30:00'], ['Race', '31/10/2022', '01:30:00']]

Comment: Can you complete the code in your question in a way that is reproducible? Like, what is in the `race_timings`?

Comment: is it this? `[['Practice 1', '28/10/2022', '23:30:00'], ['Practice 2', '29/10/2022', '02:30:00'], ['Practice 3', '29/10/2022', '22:30:00'], ['Qualifying', '30/10/2022', '01:30:00'], ['Race', '31/10/2022', '01:30:00']]`

Comment: yep i changed it in the code as well

Comment: Careful when you delete from a list you are iterating.

Comment: I just ran your code, it gets into the `if` statement just once, and it is in for the first element. And it removes it correctly!

Comment: Yes but the second element is also supposed to be removed but the output comes as timeleft is -1 days for the second element but the second element is not removed from the list

Comment: I was able to fix it but i dont understand why . I just used                                              [for i in range(len(race_timings)):] and changed all the char terms to what was necessary . It works now but i dont understand why it didnt work before